# How to get an object in a list with a given Index

Tags: c++, list

I made an array which contains a list with locations of a few teleport tiles in a game.

```
 std::list<vec2> teleportTiles[15];
```

Here it adds elements to the list:

```
        std::list<vec2>::iterator lastField = teleportTiles[Index - 144].end();
        float width = i / m_Height;
        float height = i / m_Width;
        teleportTiles[Index - 144].insert(lastField, vec2(ceil(width), ceil(height)));
```

But now I want to access a random element in this list - but how? Is there something like this: (Which would work in java)

```
teleportTiles.get(
    myRandom(0, teleportTiles.size() - 1)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (Which would work in java)

That's because Java's `List` takes many forms, most notably `LinkedList` and `ArrayList`:

> **Interface RandomAccess**
>
> Marker interface used by `List` implementations to indicate that they support fast (generally constant time) random access. The primary purpose of this interface is to allow generic algorithms to alter their behavior to provide good performance when applied to either random or sequential access lists.
>
> The best algorithms for manipulating random access lists (such as `ArrayList`) can produce quadratic behavior when applied to sequential access lists (such as `LinkedList`). Generic list algorithms are encouraged to check whether the given list is an instanceof this interface before applying an algorithm that would provide poor performance if it were applied to a sequential access list, and to alter their behavior if necessary to guarantee acceptable performance.

[<sub>Reference</sub>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html)

---

C++'s `std::list` is a double-linked list, and as such, isn't able to provide efficient random access, so it doesn't provide it at all. If you want random access, use `std::vector`. Especially if the only other operation you're doing is appending at the end.

Comment: Okay I'll try this out - thanks for the fast answer :)